# Getting FaceletContext from FacesContext in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

How to get FaceletContext from FaceletContext in JSF 1.2?

The problem is that I am creating a Tab dynamically and I want to include a view inside the newly created Tab. Including a view is supported only by FaceletContext.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
      getELContext().getContext(FacelectContext.class)
```

See [ELContext#getContext(java.lang.Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Returns the context object associated with the given key.

Comment: this does not work , it is returning NULL in JSF 1.2